# How to fix SSHD due to libssl.so.10 error?

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, openssl

SSH broke because of this, I can only access the server through VNC.

journalctl shows that errors appeared a week ago and the process stopped.

```
sshd[782]: /usr/sbin/sshd: error while loading shared libraries: /lib64/libssl.so.10: unexpected PLT reloc type 0x00
```

now the service is not starting

```
sshd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
```

```
ls -l /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10
```

shows

```
/usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 -> libssl.so.1.0.2k
```

unfortunately didn't find anything about this problem.
installed via everything by VESTACP on CENTOS 7

how can I fix/reinstall this libssl.so.10?

Comment: what about `ls -l /lib64/libssl.so.10` since that's the file referred to in the error

Comment: stupid question: How did it happen that there's a libssl.so.10 that is not the same that your SSHD shipped with on your CentOS 7?

Comment: (because however that happened, it's exactly what you'll need undo)

Comment: Also, if *you* didn't install a busted libssl.10, then *someone else* possibly did and sshd not working may in fact be the least of your worries.

Comment: @ Shadur I didn't install a broken libssl.10 and everything worked perfectly until the file was changed somehow. So I thought the same. Who did it? But I checked /var/log/secure and didn't find any suspicious activity.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Answer taken from an updated question edit</sup>

FIXED by replacing the working file `/usr/lib64/libssl.so.10`